# REACT: How to enable a disabled button by choosing specific options in a separate select element?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, bootstrap-5, react-hook-form

I am new to React and trying to implement a function in a form but I just can't get it to work. The form uses react-hook-form, axios and Bootstrap 5.2.3. I tried but couldn't make useState work, what I need is to have the Declarant's button (bootstrap tab) default disabled until I choose, inside the Baby's form, one of the correct options to unlock it ie. not father nor mother (values 10 and 1 respectively) as those two already have their own forms. How do I do it?

Edit: The files are .jsx. Using React + Vite

Here's the code in a very summarized way:

```
<h2 className="bg-primary text-light rounded-top  mb-0 pb-0 pessoaheader container">Registration Form</h2>
    <form className="form-inline container border border-dark rounded-bottom formelement" onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleSubmitForm)}>
    <br />
        <nav className="nav nav-tabs">
            <button className="nav-link active" data-bs-target="#abafilho" data-bs-toggle="tab" type="button"> Child's Data</button>
            <button className="nav-link" data-bs-target="#abamae" data-bs-toggle="tab" type="button"> Mother's data</button>
            <button className="nav-link" data-bs-target="#abapai" data-bs-toggle="tab" type="button"> Father's Data</button>
            <button className="nav-link " data-bs-target="#abadeclarante" data-bs-toggle="tab" type="button"> Declarant's data</button>
        </nav>
        <div className="tab-content">
            <div className="tab-pane active show fade" id="abafilho">
                <div className="form-filho">
                    <div className="row pt-3">
                        <div className="col-lg-2 col-md-3 mb-2">
                            <label className="formlabels" htmlFor="Declaranttype">Declarant</label>
                            <select className="form-select form-control selecttype" id="Declaranttype" {...register("Declaranttype")}>
                                <Declaranttype />
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="tab-pane show fade" id="abapai">
        </div>
        <div className="tab-pane show fade" id="abadeclarante">
        </div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg fw-semibold formbutton display-4 m-1" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form >
```

Bellow is what's in the file for Declaranttype /:

```
<>  
      <option value="10">Father</option>
      <option value="1">Mother</option>
      <option value="3">Brother</option>
      <option value="4">Sister</option>
      <option value="5">Grandpa</option>
      <option value="6">Grandma</option>
      <option value="7">Other</option>
    </>
```

Page's almost full code is also here and feedback is greatly appreciated codepen.io/caiourtiga/pen/BavwJev

Comment: Can you remove any code that’s not relevant to your issue? We appreciate *minimal* examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [watch method](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/watch) to keep track of the selected value

```js
const { register, watch } = useForm();

const watchDeclarantType = watch("Declaranttype");
const buttonDisabled =
  !watchDeclarantType || ["1", "10"].includes(watchDeclarantType);
```

then on your button, use this

```html
<button
  className="nav-link"
  data-bs-target="#abadeclarante"
  data-bs-toggle="tab"
  type="button"
  disabled={buttonDisabled}
>
  Declarant's data
</button>
```

Comment: Why not override register's onChange method instead of registering another watcher ?

Comment: @TjadClark you could maintain separate state and add your own `onChange` override but that seems exactly what `watch` is doing anyway; simply exposing the internal form data state. This to me seems like less code to accomplish the same thing and with fewer state variables

Comment: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/releases/tag/v7.16.0
It's possible to provide custom onChange handler now.  See changes - it calls the provided custom change handler within the original change handler: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/pull/5620/files

By "another watcher", I mean if buttonDisable is part of react state - i.e I want to be able to set this from other places.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies and thank you very much for the solution @Phil. Your answer worked, took me some time to realise there was a typo on my watch("tipodeclarante") and when I fixed it ran as intended. For others that might be stuck as I was, tipodeclarante is a value inside my useForm's defaultValues. Once again thank you Phil and everyone that replied.